# How to modify .Aspnetcore.Identity.Application Cookie name?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I wanna hide that i use ASP.NET Core.
The Cookie name show that i use ASP.NET Core and Identity.
So, I Would modify the Cookie name, I don't know way.
How to do this?
Somebody help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "MyCustomCookieName";
        });
    }
}
```

This works since .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

When using `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` from `Microsoft.Identity.Web` in .Net 5+, the `ConfigureApplicationCookie` method didn't work for me. I was able to change the name of the `.AspNetCore.Cookies` cookie by using the following code placed directly after the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` method call:

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookieName";
});
```